# In bash, is it possible to assign values to variables named as array members?

Tags: bash, substitution

```
# declare an array of variables
$ declare -a vars=("domain_name" "port" "username")

$ echo ${vars[0]}
domain_name

# Assign a value to it
$ let ${vars[0]}="hello"

# use the variable directly
$ echo $domain_name
5
```

Answer should be "hello"

Answer (score 1):

`declare -n` makes a variable a reference to another variable. If we do `declare -n foo=bar` then `$foo` evaluates to `$bar`, and changing `$foo` changes `$bar`.

You can use this to set `ref=domain_name`, after which assigning to `$ref` will update `$domain_name`:

```
$ declare -a vars=("domain_name" "port" "username")
$ declare -n ref=${vars[0]}
$ ref=hello
$ echo $domain_name
hello
```

You can also use it to update an array item. See the difference if we set `ref=vars[0]` instead:

```
$ declare -a vars=("domain_name" "port" "username")
$ declare -n ref=vars[0]
$ ref=hello
$ declare -p vars
declare -a vars=([0]="hello" [1]="port" [2]="username")
```

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote your very helpful answer, but it's great! Thank you!